# C# to VB AddressOf

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm more of a VB guy than c# so i have this code in c#:

```
    MouseGesture _mg;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // b) Load a file with the commands and keys once in your application
        MouseGestureData.Instance.Commands.ReadFile( 
            Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MouseGestureCommands.xml" );

        // c) For each Form you want to use mouse gestures...
        _mg = new MouseGesture( this, null ); 
        _mg.MouseGestureEntered += new MouseGestureEventHandler( 
            OnMouseGestureEntered );
    }

    private void OnMouseGestureEntered( object sender, MouseGestureEventArgs e )
    {
        // d) In your registered MouseGestureEventHandler, handle the commands
        // you want
        MessageBox.Show( string.Format( "OnMouseGestureEntered:\n" +
                                        "   Command:\t{0}\n" +
                                        "   Key:\t\t{1}\n" +
                                        "   Control:\t\t{2}\n" +
                                        "   Bounds:\t\t{3}", 
                                        e.Command, e.Key, e.Control,
                                        e.Bounds.ToString() ) );
    }
```

This is what i can come up with from VB.net:

```
Private _mg As MouseGesture

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    MouseGestureData.Instance.Commands.ReadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\MouseGestureCommands.xml")

    _mg = New MouseGesture(Me, Nothing)
    _mg.MouseGestureEntered += New MouseGestureEventHandler(AddressOf OnMouseGestureEntered)
End Sub

Private Sub OnMouseGestureEntered(sender As Object, e As MouseGestureEventArgs)
    ' d) In your registered MouseGestureEventHandler, handle the commands
    ' you want
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("OnMouseGestureEntered:" & vbLf & "   Command:" & vbTab & "{0}" & vbLf & "   Key:" & vbTab & vbTab & "{1}" & vbLf & "   Control:" & vbTab & vbTab & "{2}" & vbLf & "   Bounds:" & vbTab & vbTab & "{3}", e.Command, e.Key, e.Control, e.Bounds.ToString()))
End Sub
```

Problem being is the line **_mg.MouseGestureEntered** its saying:

*Public Event MouseGestureEntered(sender As Object, e As DcamMouseGesture.MouseGestureEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.*

What would i need to convert it to in order for it to work in VB?

Comment: Btw, you may found this tool useful: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: I find this one better personally: http://www.codechanger.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
_mg.MouseGestureEntered += New MouseGestureEventHandler(AddressOf OnMouseGestureEntered)
```

Try using:

```
AddHandler _mg.MouseGestureEntered, AddressOf OnMouseGestureEntered
```

Comment: Glad to be of help @StealthRT

Comment: Or add `Handles` after the sub-header `Private Sub ...() Handles...`.